# Hidden/Visible display depending on C# Dropdown selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, visible

To be brief, I need the Textbox with ID="textComments" to only appear when the dropdown option of 'Other' is selected from the dropdown, and then disappear if another selection is made. I could do this with JS but it needs to be in C#.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropEnquiryType" CssClass="dropdownRequestList">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Customer Services" Text="Customer Services"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Website" Text="Website"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Contract" Text="Contract Hire"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Other" Text="Other"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:label runat="server" ID="lblComments" AssociatedControlID="textComments" CssClass="textLabel">Comments:</asp:label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="200" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="40" Rows="4" ID="textComments" Wrap="true" CssClass="textComments"></asp:TextBox>
```

And help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless this is an assignment for school, I would try to get the requirement changed.  It is silly to do a postback for something so easy to control with Javascript.

Comment: @KennyZ: It's a valid specification for a team to avoid javascript. Maybe this is just an intranet application and using serverside code only is a guideline to keep it simple and maintainable.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Fair point, but it would not stop me from arguing.

Answer (score 2):

- Make the `DropDownList` first `AutoPostBack=true`
- handle it's `SelectedIndexChanged`-event
- Switch visibility of both controls there

---

aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropEnquiryType_Changed" runat="server" ID="dropEnquiryType" CssClass="dropdownRequestList">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Customer Services" Text="Customer Services"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Website" Text="Website"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Contract" Text="Contract Hire"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Other" Text="Other"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

codebehind:

```
protected void dropEnquiryType_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblComments.Visible = dropEnquiryType.SelectedValue == "Other";
    textComments.Visible = lblComments.Visible;
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim, great help. thank you. little confused about the 'DataBindEnquiryType(); function being called on the !IsPostBack though.

Comment: @wilsonlego: Deleted that part since your `DwopDownList` is not loaded from database so i assume that this is not an issue. Remember to accept one of the answers :)

Comment: the page loads with the comments label and box visible & 'Customer Service' selected, but after selecting another index it disappears and doesn't return regardless of the the option selected?

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely have to do this within C#, then a simple check in PreRender should be sufficient:

```
textComments.Visible = (dropEnquiryType.SelectedValue == "Other");
```

This will also require you to set AutoPostback on dropEnquiryType, though, which uses ... JavaScript!